# How can I store rows generated from a loop in a list? (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have the following code:

```
with open(s+ ".csv", mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for gtin,currentstock in dictionary.items():
            #if row[0] in the file is equal to the key value in the dictionary...
            if row[0]==gtin:
                #Print the row for reference and...
                print(row)
                #Create a new list that would store the output (that is several rows)
                newdetails=[]
                line=row
                newdetails.append(line)
    #print all the rows (as a list of lists?) that are produced by the loop
    print("This prints only the last line...why?")
    print(newdetails)
```

and the input is GTIN: 12121212 and GTIN 12345670 (these are the two GTINs stored in the dictionary, that I want to look up in the file).

There are two things I need to do next, and would greatly appreciate some help.

1. How can I store the results of the loop (a series of rows for instance)? At the moment, only the last row that meets the condition, generated by the loop, is stored.
2. I need to use the newlycreated(List?)to modify data in the newly created list with the VALUES in the dictionary (i.e. current stock, in this case). Again, there are multiple values, so multiple replacements, and I can't think of the best way to approach this.

The output is as follows:

```
  Want to update stock levels based on last order? - y/)y
  and here is my latest attempt.....
  ['12345670', 'Iphone 9.0', '500', '5', '3', '5']
  ['12121212', 'Samsung Laptop', '900', '5', '3', '5']
 This prints only the last line...why?
 [['12121212', 'Samsung Laptop', '900', '5', '3', '5']]
```

As per the suggestions, I have taken newline=[] out of the loop. But now it does something even more peculiar. It only prints the LAST row in the file (which doesn't meet the condition set out in the loop!).

```
  with open(s+ ".csv", mode='r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            for gtin,currentstock in dictionary.items():
                #if row[0] in the file is equal to the key value in the dictionary...
                if row[0]==gtin:
                        #Print the row for reference and...
                        print(row)
                        #Create a new list that would store the output (that is several rows)
        newdetails=[]
        line=row
        newdetails.append(line)
```

The same inputs were used (the two GTIN numbers which are printed first - so that bit work). It's the creating a new list that I need help with/ an answer to. Anyone?

Output for the above (after changes) below:

```
['12345670', 'Iphone 9.0', '500', '5', '3', '5']
['12121212', 'Samsung Laptop', '900', '5', '3', '5']
 #This is now printing the last record in the FILE.
 [['9876545', 'Acer Allinone', '550', '5', '3', '5']]
```

What I want is to store the first two rows (that match the GTIN numbers in the dictionary) in some sort of format(list, I presume?).

Thank you Jeon - based on your suggestion, I ammended the code and it works - NEARLY!!!

The code now is:

```
with open(s+ ".csv", mode='r') as f:
        newdetails=[]
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for row in reader:

            for gtin,currentstock in dictionary.items():
                #if row[0] in the file is equal to the key value in the dictionary...
                if row[0]==gtin:
                        #Print the row for reference and...
                        print(row)
                        #Create a new list that would store the output (that is several rows)


                        line=row
                        newdetails.append(line)
    #print all the rows (as a list of lists?) that are produced by the loop
    print("?!?!?!??!?!")
    print(newdetails)
```

The output is mercifully what I sort of expect it to be:

```
['12345670', 'Iphone 9.0', '500', '5', '3', '5']
['12121212', 'Samsung Laptop', '900', '5', '3', '5']
?!?!?!??!?!
[['12345670', 'Iphone 9.0', '500', '5', '3', '5'], ['12121212', 'Samsung       Laptop', '900', '5', '3', '5']]
```

So, now I have a list within a list. What I really would appreciate some guidance with is how to replace this list of lists (newdetails) by looking up the values in the dictionary. So for instance,

```
pseudocode:
if GTIN no matches index of list1 (in newdetails)
for that particular list(row), update the value of current stock, with the 
corresponding VALUE for the KEY(GTIN) in dictionary.
```

Anyone? ....

Comment: You are creating an empty newdetails during every for loop. Try moving it out of you loop.

Comment: Move `newdetails=[]` to outside the outmost for-loop.

Comment: I just suggested an edit for your code to fix the indentation. Indentation affects which lines of code belong in/out of a loop. I tried not to change what you had written, just made sure your indents were 4 spaces each. With consistent indentation, now you may see why the print is only being run one time.

Comment: Indentation looks ugly. But printing one time is just fine. But printing one line is not fine. Because of `newdetails=[]` inside a loop.

Comment: First fix where you define your `newdetails` variable by removing it from the loop. Then make a mapping between the text and the objects that are relevant, much easier to make substitutions after you have that mapping.

Comment: Also - to fully answer the question, is anyone able to answer my query (Q2). How would one go about modifying data with the values in a dictionary, for multiple rows (based on if the KEY in the dictionary matches Row[0] in the file)

Comment: Place `newdetails=[]` between `with` and `for`

Comment: Jeon - THANK YOU! I have made edits to the code and it works - nearly. Are you able to help, or is anyone, with part 2. Many thanks in advance